# $V((p))$ is a copy of $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}}$ in $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[X])$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[X])$. There is a statement such that:

For each prime number $p$, the closed set $V((p))$ is a copy of $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}}$.

I know every prime ideal in $V((p))$ should has coefficients that are multiple of prime number $p$. But how can we pass to the statement above? Hope someone could help. Thanks!

Comment: The prime ideals of $\Bbb{Z}[X]$ containing $p$ correspond to $Spec(\Bbb{Z}[X]/(p))=Spec(\Bbb{F}_p[X])$ which is the scheme definition of $\Bbb{A}^1_{\Bbb{F}_p}$ (those prime ideals are of the form $(p)$ or $(p,f(X))$ with $f$ irreducible in $\Bbb{F}_p[X]$)

Comment: In an affine scheme $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$, for any ideal $I$ of $A$, $V(I)$ can always be identified with $\mathrm{Spec}(A/I)$. Here, $A = \mathbb{Z}[X]$ and $I = (p)$.